# Grouping Results in XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

**Introduction :**

Suppose we have such a HTML code like this :

```
<div class="search-result">            
    <h2>TV-Series</h2>
        <ul>

             <li>
     <div class="title">
         <a href="/subtitles/prison-break-sequel-first-season">Prison Break : Sequel - First Season</a>             
     </div>        
     <span class="subtle count">10 subtitles</span>
             </li>

             <li>            
     <div class="title">
         <a href="/subtitles/prison-break-fourth-season">Prison Break - Fourth Season</a>            
     </div>        
     <span class="subtle count">1232 subtitles</span>
             </li>

         </ul>

    <h2>Popular</h2>
        <ul>

             <li>
     <div class="title">
         <a href="/subtitles/prison-break-fourth-season">Prison Break - Fourth Season (2008)</a>
     </div>
     <div class="subtle count">
        1232 subtitles
     </div>

             </li>

             <li>
     <div class="title">
         <a href="/subtitles/prison-break-third-season">Prison Break - Third Season (2007)</a>
     </div>
     <div class="subtle count">
        644 subtitles
    </div>
             </li>

        </ul>   

</div>
```

The page is something like this :

[image: Sample Image]

And you can see the Original site here : [SubScene](https://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q=Prison%20Break&l=)

I'm writting a C# Desktop application , that get the information of this site .

Before I learn HTML Agility Pack , I use Regular Expression .

with this pattern : `<h2>[\s\S]+?</ul>` I separate Series ( like Tv-Series , Popular and ...) .

then with this pattern on Rgular Expression : `<li>[\s\S]+?<a href="(.+)">(.+)</a>[\s\S]+?class="subtle count"[\s\S]+?(\d*)[\s\S]+?</li>` I get categorized information from this site.

with MatchCollection & using Groups ( that difined with Parenthesis) , My method in Regex , Returned me Two-dimensional list for each Serie, that each Row is about a Movie and columns include : Movie Name , Number of Subtitles and Subtitle Dowunload Link .

and that Two-dimensional list became like a DataBase somthing like this :
[image]

NOW i learned **HTML Agility Pack** .

**Question :**

**1-** How can I Create such a that list in HTML Agility Pack with XPath ?

**2-** With which XPath I can create group like Regex as you saw before ?

Thank you so much .

Comment: Grouping is better done with XSLT or XQuery or LINQ (which you can use with HTMLAgilityPack). How about showing some code you have to explain the data structures of the output you want instead of showing images? See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea for grouping examples using LINQ.

Comment: I just want to Grouping XPath like Regex ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Martin Honnen is correct, there isn't really much functionality to provide 'grouping' via XPath.  However it is possible to use a loop and run a set of XPaths on sets of elements to extract the data you want.

First, you extract each of the title elements, then extract each of the list items from the titles, and run one file XPath to pull out the values you want from each one.

*Note: This code is written using XPaths against an XDocument instead of with HTML Agility Pack, but the XPath should be the same regardless.*

```
var titleNodes = d.XPathSelectElements("/div[@class='search-result']/h2");
foreach (var titleNode in titleNodes)
{
    string title = titleNode.Value.Dump();
    var listItems = titleNode.XPathSelectElements("following-sibling::ul[1]/li");

    foreach (var listItem in listItems)
    {
        var itemData = listItem.XPathEvaluate("div[@class='title']/a/text() | *[@class='subtle count']/text()");
    }
}
```

Note the use of the XPath `|` operator in the last expression to select the values of multiple different children in a single XPath call.  The values are kind of 'grouped' like you wanted.